# rails 3, when handling a POST from a remote web app, how do we return a basic http "ok"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, render, http-post

after processing a upload file received from an external website, we need to send back some sort of basically empty http "ok" message. So we don't have a 'view' associated with this method... I assume we need to do `render SOMETHING_GOES_HERE` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `head` instead of `render`:

```
head 200
```

From the [docs](http://rails.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Base.html#M000466), it looks like you can use more readable symbols instead of numeric HTTP status codes, but I haven't found the list anywhere...

You can also include other headers, if you like (from the docs):

```
head :created, :location => person_path(@person)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

`render :text => "ok"`

You may need to pass :layout => false if there is a layout specified for the entire controller.

Answer (score 1):

```
render :nothing => true, :status => 200
```